# Automatically populate tablelayout according to horizontal and vertical free space availability

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I want to create a TableLayout and populate it with custom views all of the same width.
Would it be possible to populate it so that items are inserted horizontally and, when there is no more free space, a new row is created and populated (and so on) ?

I thought achieving this by using:

```
numColumns = myTableLayout.getLayoutParams().width / myView.getMeasuredWidth();
numRows = myTableLayout.getLayoutParams().height / myView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

But I'd be glad to know if something premade exists or if can be implemented in a better way.

Comment: have u tried with `GridView` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: `GridView` is what I want to replace because I do want a grid, but not free scrolling. So i thought of a `TableLayout` able to detect swiping and key input to go one row up/down by repopulating it.